# Box plot of one column grouped by another in pandas/matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

Let's say I have a data frame like this:

```
species,weight
lion,130
lion,190
giraffe,803
lion,150
giraffe,1200
hippo,1300
giraffe,1000
hippo,1800
giraffe,1100
lion,160
```

There are different numbers of animals per species (less, sorry - fewer - hippos, for example). I would like to make a box plot showing a distribution of weight for each species. How to?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
df.boxplot(by = 'species', vert = False)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: It provides the answer. I would know, I'm an author of the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# fake up some data
spread = np.random.rand(50) * 100
center = np.ones(25) * 50
flier_high = np.random.rand(10) * 100 + 100
flier_low = np.random.rand(10) * -100
data = np.concatenate((spread, center, flier_high, flier_low), 0)

# basic plot
plt.boxplot(data)

# notched plot
plt.figure()
plt.boxplot(data, 1)


# horizontal boxes
plt.figure()
plt.boxplot(data, 0, 'rs', 0)

# change whisker length
plt.figure()
plt.boxplot(data, 0, 'rs', 0, 0.75)

# fake up some more data
spread = np.random.rand(50) * 100
center = np.ones(25) * 40
flier_high = np.random.rand(10) * 100 + 100
flier_low = np.random.rand(10) * -100
d2 = np.concatenate((spread, center, flier_high, flier_low), 0)
data.shape = (-1, 1)
d2.shape = (-1, 1)

plt.show()
```

Not an expert in Matplotlib, but I found this code online and it looks good to me. I would just put in your values in the data sections.

Comment: If you find code available online, link to it in the comments. This is not an answer to the question.